# if i give an input signal in Volt unit to a PI control what will be the units of the output?

Tags: control, signal-theory

if i give an input signal in Volt unit to a PI control what will be the units of the output?

[image: PI control output]

Comment: It is a very, very broad question. The controller could output a voltage... but also a position, a current, etc. etc. It depends on the implementation.

Comment: well its a general question. they simply asking me what will be the phisical units in the output of the controller.
the input to the controller is an error in Voltage units.

Comment: And the answer is that the physical units of the output depends on the implementation of the controller.

Comment: they telling in the qousetion that the constatnt of the integration velocity is R=1s^(-t), if thats saying to you something

Comment: ...for example: the PI is a voltage input, force output device. Then the output would be in Newton.

Comment: they telling in the qusetion that the constatnt of the integration velocity is R=1s^(-t), if thats saying to you something, execpt that there is nothing uniq in the question.

Comment: Maybe you should not think about the units yet but consider them an "entity" being voltage, current, force or whatever. When you know what k is (at this moment you don't) then the unit at the output will become clear. But at this point, it does not matter.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the dimensions of the term 'k' in the transfer function in the box.

If the input has dimension volts, and k is a pure number, so for instance 10.00, what can you say about the output dimension?

If the input has dimension volts, and k has dimension ohms, so for instance 5\$\Omega\$, what can you say about the output dimension?

Comment: i have learned. that if i give to an I controller a signal with [rad/s], the output will be [rad], because an I controller is multiplling the signal with [s] unit.
in my case i have a [v] unit in the input. so what the units of output will be if it goes through a PI controller?

Answer (score 0):

The units of the two constant coefficients in the bracket must be consistent. For example the integrator's numerator constant may have units of \$s^{-1}\$